# How to refresh an html string in a webview?

Tags: html, cocoa, xcode, webview

My Cocoa app generates an html-table as a string which is then displayed inside a webview with:

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlTable baseURL:nil];
```

This is working fine for the first time. However, on subsequent calls of the method, the webview does not get updated, although the contents of the htmlTable string is different.

After googling for about an hour I found this method four UIWebView.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

But I cannot find it in the documentation of the "normal" webview. So, what do I have to do to refresh the webview?

Comment: Ok, problem solved. I built the WebView into a Panel and upon closing this and opening again after the htmlTable string had been changed, the WebView was no longer functional. I am now using orderOut: instead of close: and the WebView is working fine.

Comment: I was having a similar issue with the WebView being no longer functional after closing and reopening a window. I overrode `- (BOOL)shouldCloseWithWindow` and return NO.